# VSCode Intellisense - How To Prevent Arrow Keys From Cycling Through Suggestions Until Tab Is Pressed

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

In VSCode, the intellisense autocomplete suggestions occasionally pop up and prevent me from using the arrow keys to move my cursor up and down. Is there any way for me to disable the auto focusing of the suggestions until I push the tab key? (A.K.A: I want to be able to cycle through the autocomplete suggestions only after I push the tab key)

Answer (score 18):

Under Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts, find and remove the keyboard shortcuts that associate the up and down arrow with "Next Suggestion" and "Prev Suggestion". You should no longer get your arrows hijacked by the suggestions and can then use the default alternative of ctrl+up or ctrl+down to navigate them. It won't toggle on Tab like you want, but it's a good workaround.

Comment: this doesn't work for me on mac. i removed the up/down entries (which created two new entries in the user keybindings), but the arrow keys still behave the same. not sure if i'm doing it wrong or vscode bug

Comment: it was me. i removed the wrong one -- the correct command names are "showPrevParameterHint" and "showNextParameterHint"

Comment: @CoryMawhorter your comment is the exact answer. Thanks.